# Form Error - Click Send on Subdomain and redirects to Main Domain

Tags: error, forms, contact-us

After filling a form and clink send on www.domain.com/subdomain/page
it goes to www.domain.com/contacts/index/post - 404 Not Found error.

How I can fix the redirect link to go to www.domain.com/subdomain/contacts/index/post?

It's happening on every subdomain forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your form added as a cms block, you can specify the path in the form_action

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/{SOMEPLACE_ELSE}/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I have a custom nav. When I removed / from the end of the links and insert form_action="contacts/index/post" without any / in the start, somehow it worked. Thanks :)